Air extractor fan to 3 pin plugin
I have a bathroom exhaust fan with the following wiring diagram

I wanted to connect it to a 3-pin plug (Type L). Is it safe? Does it matter what side I connect the plug after doing the wiring?

sorry for delay. most our contributors are sleeping now

As the Type L plug is symmetrical, it doesn't matter which sides you connect the blue and brown wires to. The yellow/green wire needs to be connected to the middle prong.
As long as you have the plug on the side of the fan and the receptacles on the side of the house wiring, it is safe. I don't expect the fan to draw anywhere near 10 A (2200 W), so it also shouldn't matter what size of Type L plug you use.
